# Tax Query not working

Tags: custom-taxonomy, query

I'm having some trouble with my tax query. Im getting some values by GET, but it seems my tax query refuses to work:

```
$args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'imovel',
                    'tax_query' => array(
                            'relation' => 'AND',
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'finalidade',
                                'field' => 'id',
                                'terms' => $taxonomy_id,

                            ),
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'cidade',
                                'field' => 'id',
                                'terms' => array($_GET['estado'], $_['cidade']),
                                'operator' => 'AND'
                            )
                        )

                    );
```

In fact, $_GET values are coming correct, so what's wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You have a typo in `'terms' => array($_GET['estado'], $_['cidade']),` as you are missing a `$_GET`. How is `$taxonomy_id` defined? And what result are you getting? No posts found?

Comment: Beat me to it. There's that for starters. If still broken, what does `$taxonomy_id` define?

Comment: Typo fixed. `$taxonomy_id` is defined with `get_queried_object()->term_id;` to get the first taxonomy id. What's curious is that if I put a single value in `terms` like `'terms' => 11` it works.

Comment: Can you post the URL you are using to `$_GET` from just as an extra reference? You should edit/update your original post.

Comment: And if you go `echo $_GET['estado']; echo $_GET['cidade']; echo $taxonomy_id;` it correctly outputs the three proper ids you want?